# Textbox validations and color change

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am new on java-script.

I have developed a system using VS ASP.Net 4.0 using C#, i have more than 45 web forms that i want to add validations using Java-script. i have the following code for Letters and Numbers validations. see the code below.  but this code doesn't work the way i want because it can validate when you press space bar.

```
function numeralsOnly(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        alert("Enter numbers only in this field.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function lettersOnly(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
    var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode : ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) && (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
        alert("Enter letters only.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Can you please help me with the following;

1.Validate for numbers only and change color of the text box to red.

2.Validate for Letters only only and change color of the text box to red.

1. Validate for invalid email address and change color of the text box to red.

4.Validate the range of date. e.g if he/she enters invalid date like 05/05/2001 ,i need the current date.

5.Highlight the text box to red for a required text box.

Comment: Where is the mentioned code?

Comment: function numeralsOnly(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
            var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
           ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
                alert("Enter numbers only in this field.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: function lettersOnly(evt) {
            evt = (evt) ? evt : event;
            var charCode = (evt.charCode) ? evt.charCode : ((evt.keyCode) ? evt.keyCode :
          ((evt.which) ? evt.which : 0));
            if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 65 || charCode > 90) &&
          (charCode < 97 || charCode > 122)) {
                alert("Enter letters only.");
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

Comment: Please next time put your code in the question body, thanks!

Comment: Ok i will do that....

Answer (score 0):

For Question 5 : call the method in onchange or onblur method.it will validate, when you left the field.If you want validation on clicking on any of the key then call onkeyup,onkeydown.

```
   function Validations() {
  var textbox = document.getElementById("TextBox1");
  if (textbox.value == "") {
   textbox.style.borderColor = "Red";
   }
}
```

For question 1:

```
function namevalidation(){
var nametb = document.getElementsByName("TB1");
var NameRegEx = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");

var NameValue = nametb.value.trim();

if ((!NameRegEx.test(NameValue))) {
    nametb.style.border = '1px solid red';
}
else {
    nametb.style.border = "none";
}
```

}